# Apply Character Style to selection in Scribus

Tags: scribus

I'm putting together a short rule book and I thought I'd try out Scribus.   The problem I'm running in is trying to apply style to short selections of text within a text frame. Basically, I want to apply a "character style" to a section of text to override the default "paragraph style".

I've created a named style called "Rule Style" and want to apply the style to sections in the text that reference rules.  For example:

... reference *Rule 4. Doing Stuff* when doing things, but don't forget the clause in *Rule 5. Doing More Stuff* ...

I'm using Scribus 1.4.4 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have realised that unfortunately you just can't do this.
You can override almost every aspect of a paragraph style within a text box using the text editor but it's a manual process where the result is stored inline like the bad old days of html formatting.

One of the many frustrations of style handling in Scribus.